is there a built in method to remove the elements in a ruby array from another array
It's early and I feel like I'm forgetting something obvious but is there a method to subtract a array from another and return an array where the exact number of matches is removed.
# subtract operator
%i[a b a b a c] - %i[a c] # => [:b, :b]

# what I'm looking for
%i[a b a b a c] - %i[a c] # => [:b, :a, :b, :a]

Lacking a built in method, here's my implementation. Is there a more efficient way?
def remove lhs, rhs
  ret = []
  rem = rhs
  lhs.each do |val|
    idx = rem.index(val)
    if idx
      rem = rem[0...idx].concat(rem[idx+1..])
    else
      ret << val
    end
  end
  ret
end
remove(%i[a b a b a c], %i[a c]) # => [:b, :a, :b, :a]



I think you have a typo? remove(%i[a b a b a c], %i[a c]) with your code produces [:b, :a, :b, :a]

Does order matter?

For my use case, no

What about potential negative values? ie, remove(%i[a b a b a c], %i[a c c c])?

Values that exist in the "remove" array that aren't in the array to be modified can be ignored. Thank you for the additional edge cases!

Alas, my proposal for adding a core method Array#difference did not find favour with the Ruby monks. It addressed the problem here.

@engineersmnky, I like it! My effort was pre-tally and pre-then.

Here are a litany of possible options I could come up with. All options assume there can be no mutation of ary_1 and ary_2, if mutation of ary_1 or ary_2 is acceptable some of these methods can be simplified further.
Order Independent
Take your original Array and group the elements. Then we can just remove the elements in the second array from the values in the resulting Hash
ary_1 = %i[a b a b a c] 
ary_2 = %i[a c]

ary_1.group_by(&:itself).then do |groups| 
  groups.tap {|h| ary_2.each {|e| h[e]&.shift } }.values.flatten
end 
#=> [:a, :a, :b, :b] 
# or for an ary_2 with duplicates we can reduce iteration using 
ary_2_counts = ary_2.tally 
ary_1.group_by(&:itself).then do |groups| 
  groups.tap {|h| ary_2_counts.each {|e,c| h[e]&.shift(c) } }.values.flatten
end
#=> [:a, :a, :b, :b] 

Tally the counts in each Array reduce the original tally by the secondary tally and then expand back out into an Array (inspired by @dawg's post)
t1,t2 = [ary_1,ary_2].map(&:tally) 
t2.slice(*t1.keys).merge(t1) {|_,o,n| n - o}.sum([]) {|k,v| [k] * v}
#=> [:a, :a, :b, :b] 
#Or
t2.slice(*t1.keys).merge(t1) {|_,o,n| n - o}.flat_map {|k,v| [k] * v}
#=> [:a, :a, :b, :b] 

Order Dependent
Duplicate the first Array and remove the element at a found index for each element contained in the second Array
ary_2.each_with_object(ary_1.dup) {|e, obj| i = obj.index(e) and obj.delete_at(i) }
#=> [:b,:a,:b,:a]

Continually slice the first Array by selecting the values at indexes other than the index for each element in the second Array
ary_2.reduce(ary_1) {|memo, e| memo.values_at(*(0...memo.length).to_a - [memo.index(e)])}
#=> [:b,:a,:b,:a]

Partition
ary_2_dup = ary_2.dup
removed, remaining = ary_1.partition do |e| 
  ary_2_dup.delete_at(ary_2_dup.index(e)) rescue false
end 
remaining 
#=> [:b, :a, :b, :a]
removed 
#=> [:a, :c]

We could also create our own version of partitioning by capturing each element removed from the first Array in another Array
removed, remaining = ary_2.each_with_object([[],ary_1.dup]) do |e,(removed,remainder)|
  i = remainder.index(e) and removed << remainder.delete_at(i)
end
remaining 
#=> [:b, :a, :b, :a]
removed 
#=> [:a, :c]


You can do something like this:
def sub_each lh, rh
    cat = Hash.new(0).merge(rh.tally)
    lh.reject { |sym| (cat[sym] -=1) >=0 } 
end 

Result:
p sub_each(%i[a b a b a c], %i[a c])
[:b, :a, :b, :a]

p sub_each(%i[a b a b a c z], %i[a c])
[:b, :a, :b, :a, :z]

Yet another way:
def sub_each lh, rh
    lhd=lh.dup
    rh.each{|s| next unless i=lhd.index(s); lhd.delete_at(i) }
    lhd
end

Or destructively:
def delete_each lh, rh
    rh.each{|s| next unless i=lh.index(s); lh.delete_at(i) }
    lh
end


If order does not matter:
def sub_each_no lh, rh
    c1=lh.tally
    c2=rh.tally
    c1.map{|k,v| c2[k] ? [k, v-c2[k]] : [k, v] }.
        select{|k,v| v>0}.    # decide here what to do with negatives...
        map{|k,v| [k]*v}.flatten
end 

p sub_each_no(%i[a b a b a c], %i[a c])
[:a, :a, :b, :b]


If we first define #delete_first in Array, then this becomes simple.
class Array 
  def delete_first(v)
    i = index(v)
    delete_at(i) if i
  end
end

def sub(arr1, arr2)
  arr2.each { |x| arr1.delete_first(x) }
end

> arr1 = %i[a b a b a c] 
> arr2 = %i[a c]
=> [:a, :c]
> sub(arr1, arr2)
=> [:b, :a, :b, :a]

You may want to modify this to not modify the original.
